# Value returned by atoi can not be printed

Tags: c, linux, char, int, atoi

Before I present the code, a little background: I have a character pointer array by the name `math`, now, in the `while` loop I am trying to convert the value in math to an `int` using `atoi` and saving it in an `int` variable `ai`. There are no compilation errors. However, when I try to print `ai` it is not printing it. Somehow the program runs without crashing. I can't figure out what the issue is and if there is an issue the program should crash on `atoi` and if there is no issue then it should print `ai`.

The code goes like this:

```
int c1 = 3; //the array contains 3 characters 1 2 3
int c2 = 0;
while(c2 < c1)
{
    int ai;
    ai = atoi(math[c2]);
    // the array is valid, I have checked it time and again so is the content in array
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,math[c2],1); //this works fine.
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,&ai,sizeof(&ai));
    //this doesn't print anything and somehow loop goes on to meet
    //the condition.
    c2++;
}
```

Comment: what is "math[c2]"?  How is it defined?

Comment: its c2++; at the second last line, sorry for the typo.

Comment: math[c2] is a character pointer array and is defined as: char *math[10];

Comment: reading up on the "write routine, it takes in a string of characters, thus if math is a string, then math[c2] will be a character.  The output of atoi will be an integer.  Write does not take in integers.  Further you are trying to use the "reference to" ai, not ai itself.

Comment: i have tried printf("%d",&ai); this doesnt work either.

Comment: Try: printf("%d", ai); instead of write(STDOUT_FILENO,&ai,sizeof(&ai));

Comment: Because you want to print `ai` itself, not its address. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `write` is not `printf`. So

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO,&ai,sizeof(&ai))
```

will write `sizeof(int)` pieces of characters, to STDOUT; if we assume a 32-bit `int`, it will print the characters corresponding in the ASCII codetable to `(ai >> 24) & ff`, `(ai >> 16) & ff`, `(ai >> 8) & ff` and `(ai >> 0) & ff`, which is possibly four non-printable characters.

If you want to write the integer's string representation to the console, use:

```
printf("%d", ai);
```

instead.

Comment: Well, that *must* work. Maybe your char array doesn't represent a valid integer string. Did you try to compare the return value of `atoi` to the expected result?

Comment: the check doesnt seem to work.i compared:
if(ai==1){//which it should be in the first iteration
printf("%d",1);}
else{
printf("%d",0);
}

but it neither prints 0 or 1 at any point.

Comment: and is executing the rest of the code in same loop perfectly.

Comment: You have some serious trouble with your code if *neither* branch of the `if` is eecuting. Exactly one of them, either the if OR the else part must run.

Comment: yes it must, but it isnt, and i have been unable to figure out why for last 5 mins :/

Comment: its a multiprocessed client server modeled code using sockets, the IDE's debugger would do no good, dont know how to debug using konsole, i am using fedora 15

Comment: ok so i have checked the values in ai and they are all correct,as they were suposed to be. However i still cant print printf("%d",ai);

Comment: by the way i replaced printf with write in the body of if else and it worked, as my sir always said printf is not reliable!

Comment: "as my sir always said printf is not reliable!" now you're just kidding me, right?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your additional information

> its a multiprocessed client server modeled code using sockets

You probably have some additional magic in `STDOUT_FILENO`. Consider using `fdopen`, `fprintf`, `fflush` instead of the (absolutely incorrect) `write` and (possibly incorrect) `printf`.

Like so:

```
FILE* f = fdopen(STDOUT_FILENO, "w");
fprintf(f, "%d", ai);
fflush(f);
...
fclose(f); // also closes the socket
```

Answer (score 0):

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO,&ai,sizeof(&ai));
```

writes the bitpattern of `ai` to `stdout` but uses the length of the address of `ai` and not the length of `ai`. On modern machines these are usually different values `4` versus `8`, so you are writing arbitrary garbage or even produce an access error.

This is probably not what you want, anyhow.

If you want to write your number as a readable string to `stdout` use something like

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, math, strlen(math));
```

`math` has already the character representation that you want to see on `stdout`.

If you really want to pump the bitrepresentation of `ai` out there use

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, &ai, sizeof ai);
```